# PROCESS.env.PUBLIC_URl not loading images in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am using process.env.PUBLIC_URL+'image.jpg' to load the image. I am loading it in product page and I have defined the route in app.js as '/product/:productId'. It works fine if the route is just '/product'. But when adding the productid its not.. Why is it happening plz help me.

```
<Routes>
...
 <Route path="product/:productId" element={<Product />} />
...
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
<img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/image.jpg`} />
```